# ByRef argument type mismatch, what am I missing?

Tags: vba

I have this function:

```
Function hqt_dsr_Line_list(ByRef segments() As hqt_dsr_Segment) As Integer
    ...
    Dim merged As hqt_dsr_Segment
    Call hqt_dsr_Line_merge(segments(0), segments(1), merged)
    ...
End Function
```

And this:

```
Sub hqt_dsr_Line_merge( _
    ByRef seg1 As hqt_dsr_Segment, _
    ByRef seg2 As hqt_dsr_Segment, _
    ByRef merged As hqt_dsr_Segment)

    ...

End Sub
```

I keep getting a ByRef argument type mismatch. Why? It seems to me that all the types are consistent.

edit: More precisely, this is Cypress Enable (www.cypressinc.com) which is a VBA engine.

edit2: the problem is

```
Call hqt_dsr_Line_merge(segments(0), segments(1), merged)
```

the Sub seems to think the types are different. Also, hqt_dsr_Segment is a type, not a class.

edit3: option explicit is on, and the reason for the 3 ByRefs is that otherwise I get the error "User-defined type may not be passed ByVal"

Final edit: I chose to copy/paste some code in order to save time and commented the reasons for it in the code. I tried many things but in the end I think Cypress Enable might be messing things up. It is not unusual for this VBA engine to have a strange behavior, and I don't have time to find the solution (or find out if a solution exists). Thank you all nonetheless.

Comment: This is not *VBScript* (or if it is your issue is the use of type declarations) is in VB6? VBA?

Comment: @Alex sorry it is VBA not VBScript, my bad

Comment: I can't reproduce, if I make `hqt_dsr_Segment` a `Type` or `Class` then; `Dim x(1) As hqt_dsr_Segment: i = hqt_dsr_Line_list(x)` works  OK - sure about the location of the error?

Comment: Why are you running the same variable into one function as three different arguments, all `ByRef`?  This looks impractical and volatile.

Comment: Do you have option explicit on?

Comment: A sample based on your code works for me in VBA (WinWord). You could try your code in an MS VBA environment just to see if the behavior depends on the VBA compiler. It might be issue with/feature of cypress' compiler.

Comment: @Alex K asked, are you sure about the location of the error?  Under VBA Options, you might try changing the setting for Error Trapping.

Comment: Try with `Variant` and play dumb!

Comment: It looks like I might even try change hqt_dsr_Line_merge to a function that returns the merged segment instead of modifying the merge variable via ByRef.  But that's just more of a coding style, I suppose.